# Rownumber over partition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, row-number

Each employeeID has different network and customer.SoI want to have row number partitioned by
network and Customer per EmployeeID.

I tried the below code but it still gives same rownumber for an employee even if network and customer are different.

```
select distinct ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Network,CU,EmployeeiD ORDER BY Network,CU,EmployeeID)
```

I want 1,2,3 row numbers for an employee1 if he has 3 networks and also 1,2,3,4 for employee2 if he has 4 networks.

Can some one point me in right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Does each employee has only one network and customer? What's the relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it still gives same rownumber for an employee even if network and customer are different

Because you are partitioning by network and customer as well.  I think you want:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeiD ORDER BY Network,CU)
```

That will give you the relative order of each record *for each `EmployeeID`* ordered (ascending) by `Network` first, then `CU`.